# PHP 7.2 not being updated from vulnerable 7.2.10?

Tags: centos, software-collections

The version of PHP 7.2 in the current Software Collection (version 3.2) is 7.2.10, which has a number of security vulnerabilities.  From the [release notes for upcoming version 3.3](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3-beta/html-single/3.3_release_notes), it appears that SCL 3.3 will keep 7.2.10 unchanged.  I don't understand this.  PHP 7.2.11 was released in October 2018, and the latest release on PHP's 7.2 branch is 7.2.18.  What is the recommendation for addressing these vulnerabilities if SCL is choosing not to keep up?